# SQL query to get a calculated column based on few conditions on existing columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am working on a query to get a score which would be the column added to existing table and are only calculated if at least three of the five items(item1,item2,item3,item4,item5) have been completed (value is 0, 1 or 2) other wise score is set to missing and set to 99.
Score =  (sum of item value/number of valid completed items) x number of items.

The input give below in the image is from a derived table.

[image: Input and expected output]

How should I implement the query to get expected results?
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Need to be more specific

Comment: @Ullas could you please tell me what else i need to provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT item1, item2, item3, item4, item5,
        CASE 
           WHEN t.n >= 3 THEN t.s/(t.n * 1.0)  
           ELSE 99
        END AS Score
FROM mytable
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN item IN (0, 1, 2) THEN item ELSE 0 END),
          COUNT(CASE WHEN item IN (0, 1, 2) THEN 1 END)
   FROM (VALUES (item1), (item2), (item3), (item4), (item5))  AS x (item) ) AS t(s, n)
```

Comment: Thanks, I am getting Incorrect syntax near ')' end of the query and you have used "item"  within the sub query (CASE WHEN item IN (0, 1, 2)).
Please tell what i am missing?

Comment: Sorry to say getting "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'."  its here --> AS x (item), I think your way of doing is optimized one compared to other solutions.

Comment: @ Giorgos Betsos Awesome it works!! and its the optimized one thanks,
Could you please explain this code
 "FROM (VALUES (item1), (item2), (item3), (item4), (item5))  AS x (item) ) AS t(s, n)"

Comment: @mano Its a [table value constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx): it creates an in-line table using a list of values.

Comment: Thankyou for helping me out

Comment: I came across a scenario i.e for item1 and item2 with value coming as (0,1,2) which need to mapped with some other value i.e 0->2, 1->1, 2->0 , How can I handle this in the same query?
I was trying this but ran into issues  "Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference"

Comment: I can then I have to write all the content again and which would be repeated, can you add another set to handle the above situation as a appended one?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose what you are showing is table rows and item1 to item5 are the table's columns.

A very simple and easy-to-read way is to look at the items, count the ones with values 0, 1 and 2 and add them up. Then use this result to apply your formula:

```
select item1, item2, item3, item4, item5,
  case when count_items >= 3 then sum_items / count_items * 5 else 99 end
from
(
  select item1, item2, item3, item4, item5,
    case when item1 in (0,1,2) then item1 else 0 end +
    case when item2 in (0,1,2) then item2 else 0 end +
    case when item3 in (0,1,2) then item3 else 0 end +
    case when item4 in (0,1,2) then item4 else 0 end +
    case when item5 in (0,1,2) then item5 else 0 end as sum_items,
    case when item1 in (0,1,2) then 1 else 0 end +
    case when item2 in (0,1,2) then 1 else 0 end +
    case when item3 in (0,1,2) then 1 else 0 end +
    case when item4 in (0,1,2) then 1 else 0 end +
    case when item5 in (0,1,2) then 1 else 0 end as count_items
  from mytable
) summed;
```

Comment: Giorgos gave optimized way of doing this so please excuse and thus I am accepting his answer

Comment: No worries ;-) Go for which you like better and consider more readable and maintanable. I like  Giorgos' solution, but would prefer mine still, for being so easy to understand. You look at it and immediately understand how it's working (I think). But I am sure many prefer Giorgos' approach for its elegance.

Comment: Thank you for understanding

Answer (score 2):

A bit different usage of cross apply

```
with d as (
    -- sample data
    select * 
    from (
        values 
        (1,1,2,2,4),
        (9,1,9,9,4)

    ) t(item1,item2,item3,item4,item5)
)
-- query
select *, case when n >=3 then (s + .0)/n else 99 end score
from d
cross apply (
    select sum(itm) s, count(*) n from(
        select item1 itm where item1 between 0 and 2
        union all
        select item2 itm where item2 between 0 and 2
        union all
        select item3 itm where item3 between 0 and 2
        union all
        select item4 itm where item4 between 0 and 2
        union all
        select item5 itm where item5 between 0 and 2
        ) t2
    ) t
```